# ListPlot with BarLegend based on a different data source

Tags: plotting, legending

Suppose, I have the following list with `{x, f(x)}` tuples:

`fdata = {{2, 100}, {6, 90}, {10, 80}, {14, 65}, {18, 40}}`,

that can be plotted as:

`ListPlot[fdata, Joined -> True, Frame -> True, FrameLabel -> {"x", "f(x)"}]`.

However, there is another list of data corresponding to the same values of 'x' containing `{x, g(x)}` tuples:

`gdata={{2, 0.1}, {6, 0.3}, {10, 0.37}, {14, 0.26}, {18, 0.05}}`.

I want to `ListPlot` `fdata` such that the color density of the plot depends on `gdata`. I also want to add a [BarLegend](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/BarLegend.html) to the plot to indicate the variation of ‘g(x)’. Could you please help?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
Clear["Global`*"]

fdata = {{2, 100}, {6, 90}, {10, 80}, {14, 65}, {18, 40}};

gdata = {{2, 0.1}, {6, 0.3}, {10, 0.37}, {14, 0.26}, {18, 0.05}};

g = Interpolation[gdata];

gmin = MinValue[{g[x], 2 <= x <= 18}, x]

(* 0.05 *)

gmax = MaxValue[{g[x], 2 <= x <= 18}, x]

(* 0.37038 *)

Legended[
 ListPlot[fdata,
  Joined -> True,
  Frame -> True,
  FrameLabel -> (Style[#, 14] & /@ {"x", "f(x)"}),
  ColorFunction -> Function[{x, y},
    ColorData["Rainbow"][Rescale[g[x], {gmin, gmax}]]],
  ColorFunctionScaling -> False],
 BarLegend[{"Rainbow", {gmin, gmax}},
  LegendLabel -> HoldForm[g[x]]]]
```

[image]