# Combining two plots with Show and placing two BarLegends side by side

Tags: plotting, legending

I have been trying to combine two plots; each plot is similar to [this](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/272366/54258).

For the first plot -

```
fdata1 = {{2, 100}, {6, 90}, {10, 80}, {14, 65}, {18, 40}};
gdata1 = {{2, 0.1}, {6, 0.3}, {10, 0.37}, {14, 0.26}, {18, 0.05}};
g1 = Interpolation[gdata1];

gmin1 = MinValue[{g1[x], 2 <= x <= 18}, x]
gmax1 = MaxValue[{g1[x], 2 <= x <= 18}, x]

p1 = Legended[
  ListPlot[fdata1, Joined -> True, Frame -> True, 
   FrameLabel -> (Style[#, 14] & /@ {"x", "f(x)"}), 
   ColorFunction -> Function[{x, y}, ColorData["Rainbow"][Rescale[g1[x], {gmin1, gmax1}]]], 
   ColorFunctionScaling -> False
  ], 
  BarLegend[{"Rainbow", {gmin1, gmax1}}, LegendLabel -> HoldForm[g1[x]]]
]
```

For the second plot:

```
fdata2 = {{2, 50}, {6, 75}, {10, 81.3}, {14, 85}, {18, 90}};
gdata2 = {{2, 0.7}, {6, 0.8}, {10, 0.97}, {14, 1.02}, {18, 1.5}};
g2 = Interpolation[gdata2];

gmin2 = MinValue[{g2[x], 2 <= x <= 18}, x]
gmax2 = MaxValue[{g2[x], 2 <= x <= 18}, x]

p2 = Legended[
  ListPlot[fdata2, Joined -> True, Frame -> True, 
   FrameLabel -> (Style[#, 14] & /@ {"x", "f(x)"}), 
   ColorFunction -> Function[{x, y}, ColorData["Rainbow"][Rescale[g2[x], {gmin2, gmax2}]]], 
   ColorFunctionScaling -> False
  ], 
  BarLegend[{"Rainbow", {gmin2, gmax2}}, LegendLabel -> HoldForm[g2[x]]]
]
```

Then I combined them with `Show`:

```
Show[p1, p2]
```

It results in two `BarLegends`, one above the other. Instead, I would like them placed side by side. How can I achieve that?

[image]

Comment: For your code in my machine (13.1.0 for Mac OS X x86 (64-bit)) they are placed side by side.

Comment: On MMA 12.1.3 Win10-64 they show up side by side already: https://i.stack.imgur.com/BznMz.png.

Comment: Same side by side output on v12.2.0, Win7-x64. Please add a picture of what you see on your screen and the output of  `$Version`.

Comment: I am getting this - https://i.imgur.com/KWxGKOo.jpeg

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What version are you using? With v13.1, the legends are side-by-side.

```
$Version

"13.1.0 for Mac OS X x86 (64-bit) (June 16, 2022)"

Clear["Global`*"]

fdata1 = {{2, 100}, {6, 90}, {10, 80}, {14, 65}, {18, 40}};
gdata1 = {{2, 0.1}, {6, 0.3}, {10, 0.37}, {14, 0.26}, {18, 0.05}};

fdata2 = {{2, 50}, {6, 75}, {10, 81.3}, {14, 85}, {18, 90}};
gdata2 = {{2, 0.7}, {6, 0.8}, {10, 0.97}, {14, 1.02}, {18, 1.5}};
```

Plotting,

```
Show[
 MapIndexed[
  Module[{xmin, xmax, g, gmin, gmax},
    {xmin, xmax} = MinMax[#1[[1, All, 1]]];
    g = Interpolation[#1[[2]]];
    gmin = MinValue[{g[x], xmin <= x <= xmax}, x];
    gmax = MaxValue[{g[x], xmin <= x <= xmax}, x];
    Legended[
     ListPlot[#1[[1]],
      PlotLabels -> Placed[
        StringForm["f``(x)", First[#2]],
        Above],
      PlotStyle -> Thick,
      Joined -> True,
      Frame -> True,
      FrameLabel -> (Style[#, 14] & /@ {"x", HoldForm[f[x]]}),
      ColorFunction -> Function[{x, y},
        ColorData["Rainbow"]
         [Rescale[g[x], {gmin, gmax}]]],
      ColorFunctionScaling -> False],
     BarLegend[{"Rainbow", {gmin, gmax}},
      LegendLabel -> StringForm["g``(x)", First[#2]]]]] &,
  {{fdata1, gdata1}, {fdata2, gdata2}}]]
```

[image]

**EDIT:** For version 12.0

```
$Version

(* "12.0.0 for Mac OS X x86 (64-bit) (April 7, 2019)" *)

Clear["Global`*"]

fdata1 = {{2, 100}, {6, 90}, {10, 80}, {14, 65}, {18, 40}};
gdata1 = {{2, 0.1}, {6, 0.3}, {10, 0.37}, {14, 0.26}, {18, 0.05}};

fdata2 = {{2, 50}, {6, 75}, {10, 81.3}, {14, 85}, {18, 90}};
gdata2 = {{2, 0.7}, {6, 0.8}, {10, 0.97}, {14, 1.02}, {18, 1.5}};
```

Calculate the plots and legends

```
{plts, legends} = 
  Transpose@MapIndexed[
    Module[{xmin, xmax, g, gmin, gmax}, 
     {xmin, xmax} = MinMax[#1[[1, All, 1]]];
      g = Interpolation[#1[[2]]];
      gmin = MinValue[{g[x], xmin <= x <= xmax}, x];
      gmax = MaxValue[{g[x], xmin <= x <= xmax}, x];
      {ListPlot[#1[[1]], 
        PlotLabels -> 
          Placed[StringForm["f``(x)", First[#2]], Above], 
        PlotStyle -> Thick, 
        Joined -> True, 
        Frame -> True, 
        FrameLabel -> (Style[#, 14] & /@ {"x", HoldForm[f[x]]}), 
        ColorFunction -> 
         Function[{x, y}, ColorData["Rainbow"][
          Rescale[g[x], {gmin, gmax}]]], 
        ColorFunctionScaling -> False],
       BarLegend[{"Rainbow", {gmin, gmax}}, 
        LegendLabel -> StringForm["g``(x)", First[#2]]]}] &, 
    {{fdata1, gdata1}, {fdata2, gdata2}}];
```

Display in a `Row`

```
Row[Flatten[{Show[plts, ImageSize -> Medium], legends}, 1]]
```

[image]

Comment: I have been using v=12.0.0.  Probably, the problem is with this older version.

Comment: Thank you kindly. It works for me.

Answer (score 0):

What about this:

```
Legended[ListPlot[Join[fdata1, fdata2], Joined -> True, Frame -> True,
   FrameLabel -> (Style[#, 14] & /@ {"x", "f(x)"}), 
  ColorFunction -> 
   Function[{x, y}, 
    ColorData["Rainbow"][Rescale[g1[x], {gmin1, gmax1}]]], 
  ColorFunctionScaling -> False], 
 BarLegend[{"Rainbow", {Min[gmin1, gmin2], Max[gmax1, gmax2]}}, 
  LegendLabel -> HoldForm[g[x]]]]
```

[image]

??

Comment: Sorry. For my case, I can not join fdata1 and fdata2.